# Recomputing aggregates of bindable objects in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, prism, observablecollection

Say I have a main database class, `TvShowDatabase`, which contains a list of `Shows`. Each `Show` has a list of `Episodes`, each of which has a `Length`. The objects `TvShowDatabase`, `Show` and `Episode` all implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I would like to compute and show `TotalViewingPotential`, a property of `TvShowDatabase`, which sums the `Length` of each `Episode` of each `Show`.

Moreover, let's say the user is looking at this structure in a tree style, and is able to edit the `Length` of any `Show`. When they do this, the `TotalViewingPotential` should update accordingly, and the results be seen on the screen.

**My question: in WPF (and specifically, using Prism for MVVM), what is the best way to hook up the plumbing for these change notifications?**

I've considered intercepting adds to each list (using `ObservableCollection`) and giving any new items a `Parent`. This, however, gets messy, and a top-down approach is preferable.

I've seen hyper-observable collections (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/694370/How-to-Listen-to-Property-Chang), but I worry about event-subscription based memory leaks with this method, and it still requires a good bit of manual plumbing to raise the `OnPropertyChanged(TotalViewingCollection)` events where needed.

Is there a pattern for this?

Comment: You may want to look into Reactive Extensions for .NET, unfortunately I've just started looking at it so I don't feel comfortable giving you advices about it

Answer (score 0):

The task, as you describe it, has a simple solution.  You do not need to propagate changes along the collections.

TotalViewingPotential is a normal INotifyPropertyChanged property.  Make it accessible from your Length properties.

In the setter of the Length property, compute the difference between the new and the old values, and increment the TotalViewingPotential by the difference.

That's all.

To speed up initial loading, in order not to generate notifications for all Lengths, you may set the values of the backing fields of Lengths, and compute and and set TotalViewingPotential based on the values from the DB.